# "Unable to load picture or PDF file" ONLY when knitting rmd in one system

Tags: r-markdown, knitr, pandoc, xelatex

With a colleague, we are working on [this github repo](https://github.com/alecristia/nwryd19). When I knit manuscript.Rmd, I get an error "Unable to load picture or PDF file 'nwr.by.freq.ITEM'." as in [this commit](https://github.com/alecristia/nwryd19/commit/45badcf66dd5de41bd11aeb221d67ce90e9384e4). When she knits it, it works fine, as in [this commit](https://github.com/alecristia/nwryd19/commit/fc03c2ebdc6c2325f635a9b0b2f7c79c7f7b57dc).

The error comes after all chunks have been done, so it's not a problem within R/RStudio. (Plus, we are using `renv`, and I already checked for discrepancies between versions of our R, Rstudio, and packages.) The problem must come from knitting, so in the pandoc stage or thereabouts.

Given that we have some phonetic symbols (which is why we need to generate the figure in a png, and then read it back in), we are using `xelatex` as our engine, as recommended [here](https://yongfu.name/2018/09/06/ipa-symbols/). I don't think these symbols are the problem -- but I do suspect the issue is a divergence between her latex engine and mine. I'm not totally sure how to check for that...

(I'll be trying to answer my own question, so you can just wait and see if I crack this alone!)

Answer (score 3):

To begin with, I updated [xelatex](http://www.texts.io/support/0001/), which led to a missing apa6.cls error. Following [papaja install instructions](https://github.com/crsh/papaja), I would ideally re-install mactex -- but while it downloads (since it takes 1h), I just installed tinytex with `tinytex::install_tinytex()`. At my first attempt to knit the document after that, tinytex downloaded many things. And then the knit went through! Problem solved.